# How do i programmatically find common lines in files and write them into new file c#

Tags: c#

How do I programmatically find common lines in files and write them into a new file in c#?

What I am trying to achieve is directory contains 3 files. `file1.txt`, `file2.txt`, `file3.txt`
Load the files and write all common lines into `file_common.txt`

Comment: `File.ReadLines(@"pathtofile1.txt")`

Comment: Thats not what I need

Comment: Does *order* of these lines matter? Can we have duplicate lines in the same file? If yes, shall we count for these duplicates?

Comment: Duplicates can be there

Comment: Yes exactly, it will not help you 100% you have to read all line check and compare then Write to the another file

Comment: Perhaps show how you might approach it in python, and im sure we can get something similar in c#. BTW make sure you dont end up with `O(n^3)` complexity or it will be very slow.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code generation service. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried just reading the files into ```string[]``` then tried writing something. But it did not work. All it did is merge ALL the lines which is exactly wrong

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the easiest case when

1. Order of lines doesn't matter
2. Duplicates are ignored

i.e. if we have

```
file1    file2    file3
-----    -----    -----   
    A        B        A    # A / B order doesn't matter
    A        A        A    # A duplicates doesn't matter (A appears twice in each file)
    B        A        B
    C        D        B
                      E
```

the expected outcome is

```
A
B
```

you can put it as simple as

```
   using System.IO;
   using System.Linq;

   ...

   var result = File
     .ReadLines("file1.txt")
     .Intersect(File.ReadLines("file2.txt"))
     .Intersect(File.ReadLines("file3.txt"));

   File.WriteLines("file_common.txt", result);
```